# Importing matlab cell array (.mat) into a python list

Tags: python, matlab, cell

I'm trying to import a .mat file that contains a cell array.
In matlab I did this:

```
a={'element1';'element2';'element3'};
save('m.mat','-v7','a')
```

I used '-v7' because, in python, I use 'scipy.io' and 'loadmat' that can be used only with version 7. In python:

```
import scipy.io as sio
i=sio.loadmat('m.mat')
i.keys()
```

And I get:

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'a'])
```

Finally, I use the key 'a':

```
k=i['a']
```

In the variable explorer I get k, that is a object type but I can't access to its elements. How can I convert it to a list?

[image: variable explorer]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that numpy.savetxt can convert your data to csv with one string column. So, I tried to follow what it does. And I think this is what you want:

```
val = []
for row in k:
    v = '%s' % tuple(row)
    val.append(v)
```

If your data is numeric such as float, you can try this:

```
val = np.asarray(k, dtype='float').tolist()
```